# Switch two dictionaries in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, swap

I'm trying to swap two dictionaries within another dictionary.
I would like to see the following result:

```py
input: {10: {"name": "name_value1", "price1": "price_value1"}, 
        30: {"name": "name_value3", "price3": "price_value3"}, 
        20: {"name": "name_value2", "price2": "price_value2"}}
```

```py
output:{10: {"name": "name_value1", "price1": "price_value1"}, 
        20: {"name": "name_value2", "price2": "price_value2"}, 
        30: {"name": "name_value3", "price3": "price_value3"}}
```

I have tried a lot of different things and sometimes the values were in the right order but the keys weren't updated. The code below is an example of this.

```py
def my_sort(dct):
    index = 0
    key_list = list(dct.keys())
    while index < (len(dct) - 1):
        if key_list[index] > key_list[index + 1]:
            dct[key_list[index]], dct[key_list[index + 1]] = dct[key_list[index + 1]], dct[key_list[index]]
            key_list[index], key_list[index + 1] = key_list[index + 1], key_list[index]
            index = 0
        else:
            index += 1
            
    return dct
```

this code outputs the following:

```py
{10: {"name": "name_value1", "price1": "price_value1"}, 
 30: {"name": "name_value2", "price2": "price_value2"}, 
 20: {"name": "name_value3", "price3": "price_value3"}}
```

NOTE: I can't use an external library / framework for this and I can't use functions like sorted().

All help and advice is welcome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why can you not use `sorted`? Is this homework?

Comment: Is the goal to just swap? Or is the goal to actually sort?

Comment: `dct[30] = dct.pop(30)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sort_keys(keys_):
  for i in range(len(keys_)):
    for j in range(i, len(keys_)):
      if keys_[i]  > keys_[j]:
        keys_[i], keys_[j] = keys_[j], keys_[i]
  return keys_

input = {10: {"name": "name_value1", "price1": "price_value1"}, 
        30: {"name": "name_value3", "price3": "price_value3"}, 
        20: {"name": "name_value2", "price2": "price_value2"}}

keys_ = list(input.keys())
sorted_keys = sort_keys(keys_)
out = {key:input[key] for key in sorted_keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use sorted()?

```
d = {10: {"name": "name_value1", "price1": "price_value1"},
        30: {"name": "name_value3", "price3": "price_value3"},
        20: {"name": "name_value2", "price2": "price_value2"}}

dict(sorted(d.items(), reverse=False))
```

Output:

```
{10: {'name': 'name_value1', 'price1': 'price_value1'},
 20: {'name': 'name_value2', 'price2': 'price_value2'},
 30: {'name': 'name_value3', 'price3': 'price_value3'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dictionary with the key order that you need:

```
old_dict = {10: {"name": "name_value1", "price1": "price_value1"}, 
        30: {"name": "name_value3", "price3": "price_value3"}, 
        20: {"name": "name_value2", "price2": "price_value2"}}

key_ix = [10, 20, 30]
new_dict = {k: old_dict[k] for k in key_ix}
```